Constructing Wiener process on a given probability space
This is just a short question, and may be to basic, but:
is there a way to construct a sequece of independent wiener processes on a given probability spaces?

As you know, not every probability space supports a wiener process.

As long as you have a single normal random variable, you can construct a sequence of independent Wiener processes.

@mike that sounds promissing. Can you give more details please?

it's pretty standard,  the base two expansion of a uniform yields iid bernoulli's which can be put back together into infinitely many independent uniforms, which can be transformed into normals with inverse cumulant transforms & then made into as many wiener processes as you like via, say, the fourier expansion.

Do you have a response to the answer below?

$\newcommand\om\omega\newcommand\Om\Omega\newcommand\F{\mathcal F}$Let $(\Om,\F,P)$ be a probability space.

A necessary and sufficient condition for $(\Om,\F,P)$ to support a sequence of independent Wiener processes is that $(\Om,\F,P)$ be non-atomic.

Indeed, as noted in the comment by mike, it is enough to show that a necessary and sufficient condition for $(\Om,\F,P)$ to support a random variable $U$ (r.v.) uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ is that $(\Om,\F,P)$ be non-atomic.
The necessity is clear: If $A$ is an atom, then for for some real $c$ we will have $P(U=c)\ge P(A)>0$.
To prove the sufficiency, note that, by the (proof of) Sierpiński's theorem on non-atomic measures, there a nondecreasing family $(A_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ in $\F$ such that $P(A_t)=t$ for all $t\in[0,1]$; without loss of generality, $A_1=\Om$.
For each $\om\in\Om$, let now
$$U(\om):=\inf\{t\in[0,1]\colon\om\in A_t\}.$$
Then for each $s\in[0,1)$
$$U^{-1}([0,s])=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_{\min(1,s+1/n)},$$
so that $U$ is $\F$-measurable and
$$P(U^{-1}([0,s]))=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_{\min(1,s+1/n)})=s.$$
So, $U$ is a r.v. on $(\Om,\F,P)$ that is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. $\quad\Box$
